# Proof of Gauss' Theorem in electrostatics using Stokes' and divergence theorems

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis, mathematical-physics, surface-integrals, stokes-theorem

This was a problem I encountered while solving my homework.

**PROBLEM**:The potential $\phi(x,y,z)$ at any point $P$ due to the charges $q_i, i=1,2,..,n$ with respective position vectors $\vec r_i, i=1,2,..,n$ is defined by the following formula: $$\phi=\sum_{m=1}^{n}\frac{q_i}{r_i}$$

Hence prove Gauss's Law: $\int \int_S \vec E\cdot d\vec S=4\pi Q$ 
 where $S$ is the surface enclosing the charges, $Q$ is the total charge ($=\sum_{m=1}^{n}q_i$) and $\vec E$ is the electric field related to potential by $\vec E=-\nabla \phi$.

**MY ATTEMPT**: I assumed $\sigma$ to be the surface charge density and wrote
$$\phi=\int \frac{dq}{r} = \int \frac{\sigma}{r}dS$$
Now we know that $$\int \int\psi d\vec S=\int \int \int (\nabla\psi) dV =\int \int \int (\nabla (\frac{\sigma}{r})) dV = -\int \int \int (\frac{\sigma\cdot\vec r }{r^3}) dV$$ assuming $S$ encloses a volume $V$. 
I don't know what to do next. Can anyone help with the proof? 
If possible can you give a hint as to how I should calculate $\nabla \phi$?

Comment: I think you're going off a bit in the wrong direction. The problem is asking you to prove a statement relating an integral of the electric field to the sum of the charges enclosed. I see no reason to write out all these integrals you have when you already know the potential (it was given to you) and therefore already know the electric field.

Comment: @Muphrid How do I calculate $\nabla \phi$?

Comment: @Aniket Directly, just plug in what $r$ is. It's a little ugly but standard.

Comment: You could compute it directly, again knowing that $\phi = \sum_i q_i/r_i$.  You'd need to know what $\nabla \frac{1}{|\vec r - \vec r_i|}$ is. The result is well-known and easily checked...but you phrased your question as a proof "using Stokes' and divergence theorems". Maybe you want to use one or both of those instead.

Comment: @Muphrid Actually the exercise containing this problem was based on these topics. And I dont know anything about the position vectors $r_i$. So how can I calculate the gradient of $\phi$? Anyway you said the result is well-known and easily checked...Can you supply some link to help me?

Comment: Let me be a bit less subtle: you're not supposed to compute the gradient directly for this problem. (edit: you *can* do this, but that almost certainly defeats the purpose of the exercise.)

Comment: @Muphrid Not like that..I mean how do I calculate $\nabla \sum \frac{q_i}{r_i}$? $q_i$s are constant and $r_i$s are unknown. How do I carry out the operation?

Comment: I am not answering that question because the purpose of the exercise is to avoid that computation, by way of using the divergence or stokes' theorems.

Comment: @Muphrid Uhhhh..you are being unfair!! Okay, as you wish,but tell me, is calculating that gradient something elementary that I should have known at this level before working with these theorems or is this computation quite tough?

Comment: It's not supposed to be difficult at this juncture. You just need to understand that $1/r_i$ means $1/|\vec r - \vec r_i|$. Then $\vec r_i$ is just an arbitrary constant vector that is not differentiated. You should then be able to compute the gradient using the chain rule.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30746/discussion-between-aniket-and-muphrid).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider using the divergence theorem.

$$\int E \cdot dS = \int \nabla \cdot E \, dV = -\int \nabla^2 \phi \, dV$$

You will need to know what $\nabla^2 \frac{1}{|\vec r - \vec r_i|}$ is.  If you do not already know this (or have not already been told what it is), you might be able to reason out what the integral is regardless.

If not, you will have to be careful computing this Laplacian of a point charge potential. A naive computation using the derivative definition of $\nabla$ will tell you it's zero. Instead, consider using the limit definition of the divergence: for any vector field $F$:

$$\nabla \cdot F(\vec r) = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon^3/3} \int_{\Omega} F(\vec r + \hat n \epsilon) \cdot \hat n \, \epsilon^2 \, d\Omega$$

In principle, the above integral can be carried out in any coordinate system, not the spherical angular coordinates used here, but this form should be convenient for this problem.